# Realloc no execute

Tags: c, realloc

First of all,the names of variables are in greek.
It's impossible to saw all the code,because is many files.
However a have a struct

```
typedef struct{
  TTamias* Tamies;
}TPinakasTamiwn;
```

And TTamias is type

```
typedef struct{
  int  time_busy;           /*xronos apasxolhshs tou tamia*/
  int  time_inactive;       /*xronos pou o tamias einai adranhs*/
  int  arithos_pelaton;      /*posous pelates eksipiretise o tamias*/
  int  enapomenon_xronos;   /*enapomenon xronos eksipiretisi enos pelath*/
}TTamias;
```

With this function in main i create an array

```
void DimourgiaTamiwn(TPinakasTamiwn* tamias)
{
  tamias->Tamies = (TTamias*)malloc(sizeof(TTamias) * TAMIES);
}
```

After some comparisons i want to raise the size of array with this function

```
int ProsthikiTamia(TPinakasTamiwn* tamias,int plithos_tamiwn)
{
  TTamias* NeoiTamies;
  int neo_plithos = plithos_tamiwn + 1;
  NeoiTamies = (TTamias*)malloc(sizeof(TTamias) * neo_plithos);
  for(int i = 0; i < plithos_tamiwn; i++)
     NeoiTamies[i] = tamias->Tamies[i];

  for(int i = neo_plithos - plithos_tamiwn; i < neo_plithos; i++)
     TamiasDimiourgia(&NeoiTamies[i]);//fuction to initialize the data member of extra index

  tamias->Tamies = (TTamias*)realloc(tamias->Tamies , neo_plithos);//  <-----PROBLEM

  for(int i = 0; i < neo_plithos; i++)
     tamias->Tamies[i] = NeoiTamies[i];
  free(NeoiTamies);
  return neo_plithos;
}
```

The function return the new size that is raise than one.
I create a local array and copy to that the main array,
i want to reallocate the main array and copy again the local array to new main array.
Doesn't appear compile error,but in execution (also at debug) the program break at realloc.

Comment: Try `realloc(tamias->Tamies ,sizeof(TTamias) * neo_plithos);`

Comment: @Marian You should post that as an answer - not a comment.

Answer (score 1):

When reallocating, you have forgotten to multiply the dimension by the unit size. The correct line shall be:

```
tamias->Tamies = (TTamias*)realloc(tamias->Tamies , sizeof(TTamias) * neo_plithos);
```

Comment: I try that but the problem is remaining.The program stop exetution in the that line.